# Is there an operator to cancel previous execution?

Tags: rxjs

I understand that the title is weirdly formulated, but here it goes.

I subscribe on an observable `filteredBooks$` which is triggered by values emitted by the observable `this._bookFilter$`. However, the transformation is somewhat expensive and therefore I would like to cancel any ongoing executions of the `switchMap` in case a new value is emitted from `this._bookFilter$`.

How could I achieve this?

```js
  filteredBooks$: Observable<Book[]> = this._bookFilter$.pipe(
    debounceTime(50),
    distinctUntilChanged((f1, f2) => this.filtersAreDistinct(f1, f2)),
    // IF A NEW MESSAGE (bookFilter emission) COMES I WANT TO INTERRUPT THE EXPENSIVE EXECUTION BELOW  
    switchMap(
      bookFilter => findBooksByCategories$(bookFilter.categories),
      scan<Book[], Book[]>((filteredAndSortedResult, chunkOfBooksInCategories) => {
          const filteredAndScoredChunk = [];
          chunkOfBooksInCategory.forEach(bookToScore => {
            const score = bookToScore.getSearchScore().calculateBookScoreByFilter(bookFilter);
            if (score !== 0) {
              filteredAndScoredChunk.push(bookToScore);
            }
          });
          return filteredAndSortedResult.concat(filteredAndScoredChunk).sort(this.bookSortCompare);
        } , []));
      }
    ),
    shareReplay(1)
  );
```

Comment: `switchMap` already does unsubscribe on new emissions from `this._bookFilter$` but the problem you heave is probably that the computation is synchronous and therefore JS interpreter can't stop the process.

Comment: @martin: Ok, so maybe I could segment the heavy computation (the sorting) a bit in time, to give the "switchMap" a chance to interrupt...?